# Microsoft Band 2 connecting to Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, microsoft-band

I have written a little android app that can get the heart rate and 
pedometer data stream from the Microsoft Band 2. Now instead of using
a smartphone, I would like to do the same thing but now use a raspberry Pi,
so that I can further process the data. Is this possible and if so, how 
exactly should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install Android on a raspberry Pi, you just need the image of android built for raspberry pi. Here is a tutorial: https://www.squirrelhosting.co.uk/hosting-blog/hosting-blog-info.php?id=22

Also, searching for "Android on raspberry pi" on google show a lot of info, you should check more tutorials.

Tip: Android can´t be Hardware accelarated in Raspberry pi, so anything that uses UI will be a lot slower than when running on a device.

Comment: Important to note though, you will need to find buy a Bluetooth adapter that will work with the version of Android you will be using.